# How can i use @OneToMany with a connector table in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I want to create a JPA database connector for my prestashop that automatically loads my products into my shop.
I found the tables that are significant for that:

the table for generic product information.

```
ps_product
===================
id_product
...
```

the table for the features (properties for the products)

```
ps_feature
===================
id_feature
...
```

a table for the values

```
ps_feature_value
===========
id_feature_value
id_feature
...
```

and the table that connects that

```
ps_feature_products
===================
id_feature
id_product
id_feature_value
```

i tried to get a the list into my model with @OneToMany and @JoinTable

my product model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_product")
public class PSProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany
    ????????
    private List<PSFeatureValue> features;
    ...
}
```

my value model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_feature_value")
public class PSFeatureValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_feature_value")
    private long id;
    ...
}
```

How can i connect that?
How can i put the id_feature in the table ps_feature_product?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to create connection between the tables tables .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_product"){
public class PSProduct

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_product")
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product"
private List<PSFeatureValue> features;
...
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_feature_value")
public class PSFeatureValue {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_feature_value")
private long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "psproduct_id")
private PSProduct product;
```

}

Comment: Yes i tried that, but the table ps_feature_value does not contain id_product. There is the extra table ps_feature_product.

I also tried to create a extra entity for ps_feature_product, but this table does not contain any id column.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion... your tables are linked this way:

```
    +ps_product ------+
 ,->| id_product <pk> |
 |  | ...             |
 |  +-----------------+
 |
 |  +ps_feature ------+                +ps_feature_value ------+
 |  | id_feature <pk> |<----.          | id_feature_value <pk> |<---.
 |  | ...             |     `-+--------| id_feature <fk>       |    |
 |  +-----------------+       |        | ...                   |    |
 |            ,---------------'        +-----------------------+    |
 |            |                                                     |
 |            |  +ps_feature_product-----+                          |
 |            `--| id_feature <fk>       |                          |
 `---------------| id_product <fk>       |                          |
                 | id_feature_value <fk> |--------------------------'
                 +-----------------------+
```

where `<pk>` means *primary key* and `<fk>` means *foreign key*. IMHO you name fields a bit bad, as foreign keys being called the same as primary keys (I'm focusing on the `id_` prefix) tend to confound the reader, that doesn't know what is a primary key, and what is a foreing key)

IMHO you have a redundant pointer in the `ps_feature_product.id_feature` foreign key, as the `ps_feature` can be obtained by navigating the `id_feature_value` foreign key, and then the `id_feature`. This is done automatically by the ORM, and saves some data in the database.  Further, this can lead to inconsistences in the database if you make the mistake of updating one and not the other link.

Anyway, you have four entities, and you only show 2.  In my opinion, your structure should be the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_product")
public class PSProduct {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_product") /* I should have used just product */
    private List<PSFeatureProduct> featuresProducts;

    ... /* getters/setters and other stuff */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_feature")
public class PSFeature {

    @Id
    // you don't say anything on this, so I'll not use @GeneratedValue here.
    @Column(name = "id_feature")
    private long id;

    /* to obtain the values of a feature, we use the inverse mapping as
     * the relationship is OneToMany */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_feature")
    /* no column required in the database for this property */
    private List<PSFeatureValue> values;

    /* the inverse relation of which products have this feature */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_feature")
    /* no column required in the database for this property */
    private List<PSFeatureProduct> products;

    ... /* getters/setters and other stuff */
}

@Entity
@Table("ps_feature_value")
public class PSFeatureValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_feature_value")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "id_feature")
    private PSFeature feature;

    /* the list of feature/product pairs that have this value */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_feature_value")
    private List<PSFeatureProduct> featureProducts;

    ... /* getters/setters and other stuff */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ps_feature_product")
public class PSFeatureProduct {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_feature_product") /* to be consistent */
    privatre long id;

    /* this field shouldn't be necessary, as the value can be obtained
     * through the featureValue field below */
    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "id_feature")
    private PSFeature feature;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    private PSProduct product;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "id_feature_value")
    private PSFeatureValue featureValue;

    ... /* getters/setters and other stuff */
}
```

Once you have the complete set of relations, you can eliminate the ones you are not going to use, with the following restrictions:

The relations `@OneToMany` don't own the relationship (just reference the inverse `@ManyToOne` that is the owner of it) so the referenced `@ManyToOne` relationship cannot be eliminated without also eliminating this one.

Comment: Ah okay understand. Thank you!